# How to write a SQL trigger only when a one column value changes NOT updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, ssms

I need to write a trigger that populates a shadow table only when my email value is changed. My problem is the trigger I have now populates the shadow table even if the value is the same.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AspNetUsersEmail_trigger]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    -- This is where I need help
    IF (UPDATE(EMAIL))
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]([UserId],[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName])
            SELECT Id, [UserName], [Email], [NormalizedEmail],[FirstName], [LastName] 
            FROM INSERTED
END;
```

This is the code I'm using to test it

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
SET Email = 'isaac@fakemail.com'
WHERE username = 'userisaac'
```

When I run the code above twice I don't want the shadow table to populate unless the user changed their email from `'isaac@fakemail.com'`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can do this without conditional logic.  Just check if the email changed in the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AspNetUserEmailAudit]([UserId],[UserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[FirstName],[LastName])
    SELECT i.Id, i.[UserName], i.[Email], i.[NormalizedEmail],i.[FirstName], i.[LastName] 
    FROM INSERTED i JOIN
         DELETED d
         ON i.id = d.id    -- assuming `id` is a unique identifier
    WHERE d.email <> i.email;
```

If the value can change to/from `NULL`, then you'll want to take that into account:

```
WHERE d.email <> i.email OR
      d.email IS NULL AND i.email IS NOT NULL OR
      d.email IS NOT NULL AND i.email IS NULL
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but what and how do I find out what that ` i.Id ` is ? i dont understand what that is doing im pretty new to SQL to take it easy on me. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @AverageGuyIsaac . . . `i` is a table alias for `inserted`, so `i.id` is the `id` column in `inserted`.